# Order and sort array and key

Tags: php

tried searching but can't seem to find what I am looking for.

I have this array:

```
$u2 = array(
    array('bono' => 'I'),
    array('bono' => 'still'),
    array('bono' => 'havent'),
    array('edge' => 'found'),
    array('edge' => 'what'),
    array('bono' => 'I'),
    array('bono' => 'am'),
    array('bono' => 'looking'),
    array('bono' => 'for'),
);
```

Trying to output to another array like this:

```
$thatTimeU2gaveFreeMusicAway = array(
    array('bono' => 'I still havent'),
    array('edge' => 'found what'),
    array('bono' => 'I am looking for')
);
```

I just keep ending up with:

```
bono => I still haven't I am looking for
edge => found what
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: You can not have an array that uses the same key more than once, so your expected result does not make sense to begin with.

Comment: @Collin just tried the usual foreach loops and combing on key, I just end up joining the values together and not keeping order.

Comment: @CBroe - apologies, edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically an application for a *control break* implementation. You compare the value of the current loop item to that of the previous one, and based on whether they are the same or not, you react accordingly.

---

Disclaimer: If you actually like U2, then you might want to replace the variable names of course :-)

---

I am using a helper array $temp here to collect the “lyric fragments” of the current singing “douchebag”, and once the douchebag changes, they get added to the result array, and the helper array gets cleared again.

And if the helper array still contains fragments after the loop, those also need to get added then in an additional step. (For the last entry, there will not be any next douchebag to compare to any more. This could be handled differently, with a “look ahead” instead of a “look behind” - but that would complicate the loop logic a bit.)

Because of your input array structure, this needs `array_keys` to get the key of the sub-array. (Actually it would only need `array_key_first`, but that is available from PHP 7.3.0 on only, so I used the more compatible alternative here.)

```
$u2 = array(
    array('bono' => 'I'),
    array('bono' => 'still'),
    array('bono' => 'havent'),
    array('edge' => 'found'),
    array('edge' => 'what'),
    array('bono' => 'I'),
    array('bono' => 'am'),
    array('bono' => 'looking'),
    array('bono' => 'for'),
);

$thatTimeU2gaveFreeMusicAway = [];
$previous_douchebag = false;
$temp = [];

foreach( $u2 as $terrible_lyric ) {
  $current_douchebag = array_keys($terrible_lyric)[0];
  if( $previous_douchebag && $previous_douchebag != $current_douchebag ) {
    $thatTimeU2gaveFreeMusicAway[] = [$previous_douchebag => implode(' ', $temp)];
    $temp = [];
  }
  $temp[] = $terrible_lyric[$current_douchebag];
  $previous_douchebag = $current_douchebag;
}
if( count( $temp ) ) {
  $thatTimeU2gaveFreeMusicAway[] = [$previous_douchebag => implode(' ', $temp)];
}

var_dump($thatTimeU2gaveFreeMusicAway);
```

Comment: Thank you for both answer and explanation learnt something, so thanks

Answer (score 2):

This just keeps track of where the last word was stored (against the person) and checks if it has changed, if it has then move onto the next entry...

```
$output = [];
$last = -1;
foreach ( $u2 as $word )    {
    $who = key($word);
    // If first time or the current who doesn't match the last one
    if ( $last == -1 || key($output[$last]) != $who )   {
        $last++;
        // Make sure new entry exists
        $output [$last][$who] = '';
    }
    // Add in the new word
    $output [$last][$who] .= ' '.current($word);
}
```

Comment: @Tajniak, please don't just edit answers if you would do things slightly differently.  You can add a new answer if you think your solution is an improvement or leave a comment about what you would change.

Comment: That answer is incorrect. Adds whitespace at the beginning of new line.

Comment: @Tajniak, there is nothing wrong with pointing out errors and even suggesting improvements (as in your answer), I think it's a case of making your point and moving on.